# How to extract excel data in html webpage

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I have stored a list of country, capital, currency, area, population, prime minister, president in an excel spreadsheet and I want the user to choose a country from the dropdown list and then the other parameters(capital, currency, etc.) will be shown as output in a webpage. How can I do this in HTML?

Comment: I would say [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=import+excel+to+html) is a good place to start ;)

Answer (score 0):

use XLSX.js to extract the spreadsheet as arrays and do anything with the arrays that is extracted.